# Default tab setting upon page load

Tags: html, css, tabs

How do I set the default tab to be 'active' or 'viewed'?
As far as I understand the code below should set the 'add user' as the active tab and display the content in #addUser upon page load but not in my case. The add user tab is not displayed and I have to click on the other tabs and back at the add user tab again to see the content. Am I missing something? Most of my research returns me to set a class as active but still isn't working for me.

```
<li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#addUser" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User
    </a>
</li>
```

Here's the code for the creation of the tabview.

```
<div class="content-body">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#addUser" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#rUser" role="tablist" data-toggle="tab">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove User
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#eUser" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit User
            </a>
        </li>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use cookies.

Comment: @dehood what do you mean?

Comment: Take a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I01XMRo2ESg

Answer (score 0):

based on this the only thing i see is that you forgot to close your ul tag at the end.

Comment: closing the ul does not changes anything too. XD